# box-shadow showing up to the left side of an image only

Tags: jquery, html, image, css, box-shadow

I am appending an `img` element through jQuery and trying to add a `box-shadow` to all sides of the image on click event. However the shadow only shows up at the left side of the image. How can I add a shadow on all sides of the image?

```js
var someNumbers = [1, 2, 3];

$.each(someNumbers, function(index, element) {
  $('#collection').append('<img src="' + someNumbers[index] + '"/>');
});

$('#collection img').on({
  click: function() {
    $('#mainImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    $(this).addClass('selectedImgStyle');
  }
});
```

```css
#collection {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#collection img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selectedImgStyle {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collection"></div>
```

Comment: This is caused by the overflow on the `#collection`. Short of adding some `margin` to the `img` to allow space for the `box-shadow`, there's not a lot you can do

Answer (score 0):

You have specified blur-radius of 50px. So, if the size of the image on one side is more than 50px, it will not be visible. A better way is to use 2 values for box shadow.

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red, -2px -2px 2px red;
```

Hope it helps.If that does not solve the problem, please share a screenshot.

Comment: You can see by editing the snippet this doesn't achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest playing round with your **overflow** properties. Sometimes if a container isn't big enough and you don't have the proper visibility things can get cut off (like box-shadow's). Even if you have something set to scroll, the box-shadow doesn't count as "extra content" to an element therefore making it non-scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

```
.selectedImgStyle{
box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
}
```